# Product of 2 dice game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

---

> You are playing a game where you a paid the product of 2 dice

> a) How much would you pay to have the opportunity to reroll any 1 of the dice?

> b) How much would you pay to roll 3 dice and discard the lowest?

---

I know the EV of product of 2 dice is 12.25

I calculated the Probability of the Product of 2 dice to be <= 12 as $ \frac {23} {36} $

Similarly the probability of the Product of 2 dice to be > 12 as $ \frac {13} {36} $

Now for Part a) New E.V. = $ \frac {23} {36} $ * (Increase in EV in this case) + $ \frac {13} {36} $ * (0 Increase)

However, I'm confused how to approach the Increase in EV in the case where we choose to reroll 1 of the dice with Probability of 23/36.

One approach I can think of for the above case is that we would only reroll a 1,2 or 3 and never a 4,5,6 as (4 * 4 = 16), (5 * 5 = 25), (6*6 = 36) is > than 12.25.

Then - $$  \frac {1} {3}  * (3.5-1) +  \frac {1} {3}  * (3.5 -2) +  \frac {1} {3}  * (3.5-3) = 1.5 $$

**Now, I'm not sure if it should be $ \frac {1} {3}  or   \frac {1}{6} $ for the probabilities above considering that it is conditioned on rerolling only if we get a 1,2 or 3**

Now the 2nd die E[x] = 3.5 so we can say $$ 1.5 * 3.5 = 5.25 $$ which would be the increase in EV in the case where we choose to reroll 1 of the die

Hence increase in EV = $$  \frac {23} {36} * 5.25 = \frac {161} {48} $$

Not sure if this approach is correct

Part b) I'm not sure how to approach it

Comment: Wondering if there is a way to do it without explicitly calculating for all the 23 cases where the product is < 12.25. I know the answer above is wrong using code so trying to figure out what is wrong an the best way to approach this without explicitly calculating all cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) Given the opportunity to reroll a singular dice, we note that this only makes sense to do if the number it is currently showing is $3$ or less, as the expected value of the reroll is $3.5$. Hence, the new expected value of a roll of $(m, n)$ is $3.5 \max(m, n)$ if any of $m$ or $n$ are $\leq 3$, and otherwise it remains $mn$. Splitting into $4$ cases, we have

*Case 1*: $m, n \geq 4$

In this case, we choose not to reroll, so the total sum of products is $(4+5+6)(4+5+6) = 15^2$.

*Case 2*: $m \geq 4$, $n \leq 3$

In this case, we choose to reroll the $n$-die, so the total average sum of products is $(4+5+6)(3\times 3.5) = 3 \times 3.5 \times 15$.

*Case 3*: $m \leq 3$, $n \geq 4$

This case is virtually the same as previous, and we get the same total.

*Case 4*: $m, n \leq 3$

In this case, we choose to reroll the smaller die, so the total average sum of products is $5 \times 3.5 \times 3 + 3 \times 3.5 \times 2 + 1 \times 3.5 \times 1$.

this gives an overall expected value of
$$\frac{15^2}{36} + 2 \cdot \frac{3 \times 3.5 \times 15}{36} + \frac{5 \times 3.5 \times 3 + 3 \times 3.5 \times 2 + 1 \times 3.5 \times 1}{36} = \boxed{\frac{617}{36}}$$
Hence, you should be willing to pay up to $\frac{617}{36}$ to play this game (or $\frac{44}{9}$ more than the game without any reroll).

(b) We break this up into cases depending on what the smallest number is:

*Case 1*: Smallest number is $1$.

There are $91$ possible ways of this occurring, with total sum of product being $1 \times 1^2 + 3 \times 1 \times 20 + 3 \times 20^2 = 1261$.

*Case 2*: Smallest number is $2$.

There are $61$ possible ways of this occurring, with total sum of product being $1 \times 2^2 + 3 \times 2 \times 18 + 3 \times 18^2 = 1084$.

*Case 3*: Smallest number is $3$.

There are $37$ possible ways of this occurring, with total sum of product being $1 \times 3^2 + 3 \times 3 \times 15 + 3 \times 15^2 = 819$.

*Case 4*: Smallest number is $4$.

There are $19$ possible ways of this occurring, with total sum of product being $1 \times 4^2 + 3 \times 4 \times 11 + 3 \times 11^2 = 511$.

*Case 5*: Smallest number is $5$.

There are $7$ possible ways of this occurring, with total sum of product being $1 \times 5^2 + 3 \times 5 \times 6 + 3 \times 6^2 = 223$.

*Case 6*: Smallest number is $6$.

There is $1$ possible ways of this occurring, with total sum of product being $1 \times 6^2 = 36$.

Hence, the expected value of the game is $\boxed{\frac{1967}{108}}$, so this is the maximum you should consider paying.

Comment: @quantrader23 I’ve outlined how each expression comes out from the cases. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The first roll is modeled by the random variables $X_1,X_2$. Let $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}$ denote the order statistics.

Consider always replacing the smaller $X_{(1)}$ with a new roll $Y$. The expected value of the final payoff is $E[X_{(2)} Y] = 2E[X_1 Y 1_{X_2<X_1}] + E[X_1 Y 1_{X_2=X_1}] = E[Y](\frac 2{36} [\sum_{i,j}i 1_{j<i}] +\frac 1{36} \sum_i i ) = \frac {1127}{72}\approx 15.6$.

A strategy is then to reroll the smallest die if and only if $X_1X_2 < \frac {1127}{72}$.

As suggested in the comments section, a more sensible strategy is to reroll the smallest die with face $\leq 3$ (if any, otherwise no second roll). The expected payoff is then

$$\begin{aligned}
&\phantom{=}E[X_1X_2 1_{\min(X_1,X_2)\geq 4} + X_{(2)}Y 1_{\min(X_1,X_2)\leq 3}]
\\&=
E[X_1X_2 1_{\min(X_1,X_2)\geq 4}] + 2E[X_1 Y 1_{X_2<X_1}1_{\min(X_1,X_2)\leq 3}]
+E[X_1 Y 1_{X_2=X_1}1_{\min(X_1,X_2)\leq 3}]
\\&= 
25/4 + 371/36 + 7/12 = \frac{617}{36} \approx 17.1.
\end{aligned}$$

---

For the second question, you're looking for $E[X_{(2)} X_{(3)}]$, which can be decomposed as
$$E[X_{(2)} X_{(3)}1_{\text{no ties}}]
+E[X_{(2)} X_{(3)}1_{\text{a single tie}}] 
+E[X_{(2)} X_{(3)}1_{\text{all equal}}].$$

$E[X_{(2)} X_{(3)}1_{\text{no ties}}] = 
E[\sum_{\sigma\in S_3} 
X_{\sigma(2)} X_{\sigma(3)} 1_{X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<X_{\sigma(3)}}] = 3! E[ 
X_{2} X_{3} 1_{X_{1}<X_{2}<X_{3}}] = \frac{21}2.$
I used [Mathematica](https://i.imgur.com/xNhmd2h.png) for the last computation.

$E[X_{(2)} X_{(3)}1_{\text{a single tie}}] 
= 3E[X_2^21_{X_1<X_2}1_{X_2=X_3}] + 3E[X_1 X_2 1_{X_1>X_2}1_{X_2=X_3}] = \frac{175}{24}.$

$E[X_{(2)} X_{(3)}1_{\text{all equal}}] = \sum_{i=1}^6E[i^21_{X_1=X_2=X_3=i}] = \frac{91}{216}.$

Finally, $$E[X_{(2)} X_{(3)}] = \frac{1967}{108}\approx 18.2.$$

This value is confirmed by the following numpy simulation:

```
import numpy as np
sample = np.random.randint(1,7,(10000,3))
sample_s = np.sort(sample)[:,1:]
print(np.mean(sample_s[:,0] * sample_s[:,1]))
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure your initial strategy is suboptimal due to a subtlety you have missed. For example, if you rolled $6$ and $3$, then your strategy is to not reroll the $3$, but it actually makes more sense to reroll since your expected product is $21$. Using your strategy, I  determined that the expected winnings is $\frac{57}{4}$, but using my strategy yields $\frac{617}{36}$.